# How to scale a website for mobile devices?

Tags: android, css, iphone, mobile-website

I've a very simple static web page (only css and links, no scripts).
It looks good on android and iphone, but too small. I'm guessing they put it smaller since it work for most of the sites. 
How can I override this and make him look the size I want it to be?

Comment: Whatever you go with, make sure you test in newer versions of Android. I had a nice simple single column layout that looked OK in Android 1.5 and Android 1.6. Android 2 seems to crush all the text into a little sliver on the side, though. Bizarre that I'm going to have to switch to a multi-column layout to support a phone, where simpler should be better.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Android automatically adjusts to the size of your site, try to use width:100% or smaller than around 310 pixels (scrollbar takes space) for normal viewmode.

For IPhone try using this code to force the correct size

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
```

Also to force font-size try to use this code in your css:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

The list should be comma-separated.