# Font size relative to parent box height

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-website, mobile-webkit

I have block level elements with its `height` property set in `%`. Inside these block level elements are `<span>`s with text. Example:

```
<body style="height: 100%;">
    <menu style="height: 10%;">
        <button style="display: block; height: 100%;">
            <span style="font-size: 4em; line-height: 200%;">text</span>
        </button>
    </menu>
</body>
```

This looks fairly well on a mobile browser, except when I rotate the device (that is, once the `body.onorientationchange` event kicks in), the text becomes too big.

So my question is, how can I specify the text size relative to the height of the parent element?

Comment: Post your update as an answer and accept it. If you've found a solution yourself, **IT IS** OK to accept your own answer :) I forgot about the `meta` tag, but keep the `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;` in mind since I've fixed a very weird text-size issue on an input box with it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will disable font size change on rotation, which pretty much solves my problem. Borrowed [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361846/how-to-scale-a-website-for-mobile-devices).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0">
```

**UPDATE:** changed from semicolons to commas as [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807423/mark) suggested.

Comment: One can only his/her own answer after two days, remember? A fow more hours to go...

Comment: If you use semi-colons between the content arguments, you'll get an error on Safari. It works fine if you replace the semi-colons with commas.

Comment: @Mark I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out, though I did not notice the error so far, do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Attila, almost everywhere I see semi-colons being used instead of commas and this puzzles me. For now, the only reference I have is Safari itself (check the error console).

Answer (score 1):

I've run into similar issues on the iPhone and it wasn't the height causing the issue, but rather an option of mobile webkit.

Try setting this

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Comment: Nice! But according to [this link](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-text-size-adjust) in only applies for Mobile Safari on iOS. Is there an alternative for the default Android browser?